# How to add a single combobox into a datagridview in random positions

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to add DatatGridViewComboBoxCell into dynamically determined cells onto the datagridview.

So far all of the examples I have found either make the entire columns' cells into comboboxes or don't work.

Here is the simplest example that I can come up with. I have tried databinding to sources which work to a point. The items exist in the combobox.items but on the datagridview the combobox is empty and you cannot select a value

[image: ComboBox with no items being displayed]

```
DataGridArticles.Columns.Add("columna", "columna")
Dim combo As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell

combo.Items.Add("b")
combo.Items.Add("ba")
combo.Items.Add("ca")

DataGridArticles.Rows.Add()
DataGridArticles.Rows(0).Cells(0) = combo
```

Is it possible to add a combobox to a specific cell in a datagridview.

Comment: Can you write why DataBound `ComboBoxCell` didn't work fully? Never had any problems with it.

Comment: like I said the data is in the combobox when debugging but you cannot see anything in the combobox on the datagridview. I'll add an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never had any problems with DataBound `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.

I'm using it like this:

```
Dim cell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell()
cell.DisplayMember = "Name"
cell.ValueMember = "Id"
cell.DataSource = list

DataGridArticles.Rows(0).Cells(0) = cell

cell.Value = 0 //It will select and display item with Id = 0, if you do not set it
               //then combobox will look exactly like yours on image posted (like
               //there is no items in it).
```

It worked flawlessly every time I used it. So if it does not work for you may.

So to fix your problem add this line after adding items to combobox:

```
combo.Value = "b";
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That does indeed help but when I click on the combobox it does not dropdown at all.

Comment: Please check if: 1. Cell is not `ReadOnly` 2. Row is not `ReadOnly` 3. Does `GridView` have `Enable Editing` Checked?